# Off chain worker for https:// request

Tags: polkadot, rpc, pallet-contracts

I have a simple question if i use `off chain workers` to get calls to https://somecoinexchange/ to get data for `some calculation`, what will be the `gas usage`. I was presuming that since no chain work is done, no gas will be used.

Answer (score 1):

FRAME doesn't use the concept of gas. It uses weight, which is currently determined based on running benchmarks on some standard hardware. However, everything that runs in `offchain_worker` doesn't use any weight at all. The runtime code itself is seen as trusted code, but nodes are still allowed to opt-out from running `offchain_worker`.

TDLR: Your assumption that no weight/gas is being used is correct.